# How can I find the derivative of this integral?

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus

A function is defined for a constant $x$ after integrating out with variable $t$ as:

$$ F(x) = \int_0^4 \log(1-x^2t^2)\,dt  $$

making it as a function of $x$. How can I now find $ F(x=0)$ and $ F'(x) $ ?

Answer (score 1):

first, $F(0) = \int_0^4 \ln(1) dt = 0.$

$$\begin{align}F'(x)=\frac d{dx}\int_0^4 \ln(1-x^2t^2)\, dt &= \int_0^4 -2x\frac{t^2}{1-x^2t^2} \, dt\\
&= -2x\int_0^4\left(-\frac 1{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^2(1-t^2x^2)}\right)\, dt\\
&= \frac 8x -\frac 1x\int_0^4 \left(\frac 1{1-tx}+\frac 1{1+tx}\right)\, dt\\
&=\frac 8x - \frac 1{x^2} \ln\left(\frac{1+tx}{1-tx}\right)\Big|_0^4 \\
&=\frac8x-\frac1{x^2}\ln\left(\frac{1+4x}{1-4x}\right)  \end{align}$$

---

$\bf edit:$
$$\begin{align} F''(x) &= -\frac{8}{x^2}+\frac{2}{x^3} \ln\left(\frac{1+4x}{1-4x}\right) - \frac{1}{x^2}\left( \frac 4{1+4x}+ \frac 4{1-4x}\right) \\
&=\frac{8}{x^2} -\frac{8}{x^2(1-16x^2)}+\frac{2}{x^3} \ln\left(\frac{1+4x}{1-4x}\right) \\
&=-\frac{128x^2}{(1-16x^2)} + \frac{2}{x^3} \ln\left(\frac{1+4x}{1-4x}\right)\end{align}$$

Comment: So F'(0) = 0 ? How i can find concavity of grapgh F(x) ? its the second derive?

Comment: @BrunoCruz, yes. take the derivative of the expression $F'(x)$ in the last line. $F$ is concave up in the region $F'' > 0.$

Comment: Abel, can give expression of second derivative? Because i founf down concave, have mistake from me right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint for the first question. [This wikiedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign#Examples) give the general result that

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t) dt = f(x,b(x))b'(x)-f(x,a(x))-a'(x)+ \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x)$$

In your case, you have constant bounds, so $b'(x) = a'(x) = 0$. Thus we have:

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \int_{0}^{4} \log(1-x^2 t^2) dt = \int_{0}^{4} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \log(1-x^2 t^2) dt$$

Can you complete it from there? Also, for the second question, what have you tried? It should be as simple as replacing $x$ by $0$ in your expression.